# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'name' and 'id'

Tags: java, android

//MAIN ACTIVITY.java..........

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;    
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
       private class Person {
        Spy mySpy = new Spy(name:"Frank", id:24851)
    }
}
```

//Spy.java

```
package com.example.helloworld;

public class Spy {

    public String name;
    public int id;

    public Spy(String name, int id){
        this.name= name;
        this.id= id;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: `Spy mySpy = new Spy(name:"Frank", id:24851);` is an incorrect way of setting values of `Spy` object. You need to do this: `Spy mySpy = new Spy("Frank", 24851);` You don't need to specify `name` and `id` in the constructor, just provide the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this (kotlin way):

```
 Spy mySpy = new Spy(name:"Frank", id:24851)
```

to this (java way):

```
 Spy mySpy = new Spy("Frank", 24851)
```